# What other settings could prevent the "Go to Label" feature working in Google Mail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

The "Go to Label" Lab feature should work as follows:

- Press <kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>l</kbd> (**g**oto **l**abel)
- Hovering input box opens
- Start typing a label's name or a folder name (Inbox, Trash, etc.)

  - Suggestions appear as I type to a dropdown list
- Select a label from the list / type the whole label
- Submit
- Page `in:<name>` (or `label:<name>`) opens

<del>**HOWEVER** When I trigger the keyboard shortcut, hovering input box opens with `l` already put*. Suggestions won't appear. Nothing happens when I press enter.</del>

`2011-06-30` Pressing <kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>l</kbd> won't even show the input box anymore.

The feature is broken. I have tried Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera on OS X.

I have the following other Labs features enabled**:

- Extra Emoji
- Search from autocompletion
- Undo send
- Add images
- Unread messages icon
- Send & Archive
- Mark as read button
- Title improvements
- Fetch POP-accounts
- Recently used Emoji
- Signature tweaks
- Go to label *(duh)*
- Message peek

**Are any/some/a combination of these known to be in conflict with the "Go to label"?** With my current Labs settings there is quite a lot of possible combinations, so trial & error might not be worth the hassle as I still can use the search box and click on the labels on the list on the left.

Also @[Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-everett) confirmed the Go to Label works for him as advertised, so I *believe* some other Lab feature is preventing it from working correctly. (I might investigate this, unless someone knows the answer straight away.)

For what it's worth, I actually have Google Apps mail — but a [help article](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=34383) suggests the versions don't differ that much.

---

<del>*) The `l` isn't input in Firefox, otherwise it (dys)functions the same</del>
**) These are translations from their Finnish namesakes so it may not be 1:1 correct.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; it works as advertised for me. Is this still happening to you?

Comment: @Al now that you mention it, pressing `g` then `l` will not do anything anymore for me; won't even show the input box (tested Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari on OSX). Could you tell me what other Lab features you are using?

Comment: A lot of them. I'm **not** using mouse gestures or custom keyboard shortcuts, which I think would be most likely to interfere. I'm also not using Google Apps, which may be the key difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is in the **language versions**:

- Tried vanilla GMail account (w/ keyboard shortcuts turned on) with all the same Labs enabled → not working
- Disabled all other Labs but "go to label" → not working
- Switched language to "English (US)" → works

I tested some other languages as well. Both English US & UK seem to be the only ones that have working Go to label feature. (I was going through the language list alphabetically and when all Spanish, German and French failed, I stopped.)

Changing the language to English in my primary Google Apps Mail account "solved" the problem there too.

---

**UPDATE** Using the [Gmail's new look](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/gmails-new-look.html) also seems to fix the issue. (Well at least for Finnish, so probably for other languages as well.)

Comment: Thanks Koiyu, you hit the point! this is a language issue.
I changed into english and now "g+l" works again.
It's kinda weird because I have always used the same language in gmail (catalan) and "g+l" worked as well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the solution for me was to disable the "Preview Pane" Gmail lab.

Comment: Disabling the "Preview Pane" fixed this for me. Thanks Ben.